# nexus oss 3.12.1-01 migrate to new machine fails during upgrade

Tags: nexus

I am trying to move my nexus oss install from 1 machine in my intranet to an instance in AWS.

I have tried a couple of things with little success.

1. Stop server; copy sonatype-work folder to new machine; start new server (using same paths) - tons of errors durring startup
2. Same as 1, but use export of all databases (delete $data-dir/db/xxx; put bak files in restore-from-backup folder)

second attempt is giving this error now:

```
2018-07-10 10:22:35,520-0400 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM 
org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - Upgrade component from 1.10 to 1.11
2018-07-10 10:22:35,526-0400 ERROR [FelixStartLevel <query>select from repository where recipe_name in ['docker-hosted', 'docker-proxy']</query>]  *SYSTEM ROOT - Exception `7F9E2708` in storage `plocal:/maven/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config`: 2.2.34 (build f340442755a31eabc91b87cb3ef99eda5cee6ebd, branch 2.2.x)
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException: Error on parsing query at position #11: Error on parsing query
Query:  repository WHERE recipe_name IN ['docker-hosted', 'docker-proxy']
----------------^
DB name="config"
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLTarget.<init>(OSQLTarget.java:74)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OSQLEngine.parseTarget(OSQLEngine.java:464)
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me with a HA implementation of Nexus, renaming the DB folder inside sonatype-work to db.old and starting nexus again worked. It grabs the folder from another node...however in a single node installation this solution will not work, the db folder will get recreated but you will loose your data.